# Bash: create anonymous fifo

Tags: bash, script, pipe

We all know `mkfifo` and pipelines. The first one creates a *named* pipe, thus one has to select a name, most likely with `mktemp` and later remember to unlink. The other creates an anonymous pipe, no hassle with names and removal, but the ends of the pipe get tied to the commands in the pipeline, it isn't really convenient to somehow get a grip of the file descriptors and use them in the rest of the script. In a compiled program, I would just do `ret=pipe(filedes)`; in Bash there is `exec 5<>file` so one would expect something like `"exec 5<> -"` or `"pipe <5 >6"` -is there something like that in Bash?

Answer (score 63):

You can unlink a named pipe immediately after attaching it to the current process, which practically results in an anonymous pipe:

```
# create a temporary named pipe
PIPE=$(mktemp -u)
mkfifo $PIPE
# attach it to file descriptor 3
exec 3<>$PIPE
# unlink the named pipe
rm $PIPE
...
# anything we write to fd 3 can be read back from it
echo 'Hello world!' >&3
head -n1 <&3
...
# close the file descriptor when we are finished (optional)
exec 3>&-
```

If you really want to avoid named pipes (e.g. the filesystem is read-only), your "get a grip of the file descriptors" idea also works. Note that this is Linux-specific due to the use of procfs.

```
# start a background pipeline with two processes running forever
tail -f /dev/null | tail -f /dev/null &
# save the process ids
PID2=$!
PID1=$(jobs -p %+)
# hijack the pipe's file descriptors using procfs
exec 3>/proc/$PID1/fd/1 4</proc/$PID2/fd/0
# kill the background processes we no longer need
# (using disown suppresses the 'Terminated' message)
disown $PID2
kill $PID1 $PID2
...
# anything we write to fd 3 can be read back from fd 4
echo 'Hello world!' >&3
head -n1 <&4
...
# close the file descriptors when we are finished (optional)
exec 3>&- 4<&-
```

Comment: You can combine this with automatic finding of unused file descriptors: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8297415/in-bash-how-to-find-the-lowest-numbered-unused-file-descriptor

Comment: I got some deadlocks when I used the first technique in my script instead of using without file descriptors.

Comment: The `-u` in `mtemp -u` means unsafe; the name was not actually allocated. Another process can get the same name. In that case, `mkfifo` will fail; so this can be looped around until it works.

Answer (score 30):

While none of the shells I know can make pipes without forking, some do have better than the basic shell pipeline.

In bash, ksh and zsh, assuming your system supports `/dev/fd` (most do nowadays), you can tie the input or the output of a command to a file name: `<(command)` expands to a file name that designates a pipe connected to the output from `command`, and `>(command)` expands to a file name that designates a pipe connected to the input of `command`. This feature is called **process substitution**. Its primary purpose is to pipe more than one command into or out of another, e.g.,

```
diff <(transform <file1) <(transform <file2)
tee >(transform1 >out1) >(transform2 >out2)
```

This is also useful to combat some of the shortcomings of basic shell pipes. For example, `command2 < <(command1)` is equivalent to `command1 | command2`, except that its status is that of `command2`. Another use case is `exec > >(postprocessing)`, which is equivalent to, but more readable than, putting the whole rest of the script inside `{ ... } | postprocessing`.

Comment: I tried this with diff and it worked but with kdiff3 or with emacs, it didn't work.  My guess is that the temporary /dev/fd file is being removed before kdiff3 gets to read it.  Or perhaps kdiff3 is trying to read the file twice and the pipe is only sending it once?

Comment: @Eyal With process sustitution, the file name is a “magic” reference to a pipe (or a temporary file on Unix variants that don't support these magic variants). How the magic is implemented depends on the OS. Linux implements them as “magic” symbolic links whose target is not a valid file name (it's something like `pipe:[123456]`). Emacs sees that the symlink's target is not an existing file name and that confuses it enough that it doesn't read the file (there may be an option to get it to read it anyway, though Emacs doesn't like opening a pipe as a file anyway).

Comment: Unfortunately process substitution is pretty much useless in any serious script, since grabbing the `$?` of the child process is so tricky, that using named pipes will be certainly more readable.

Answer (score 13):

Bash 4 has [coprocesses](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Coprocesses).

> A coprocess is executed asynchronously in a subshell, as if the command had been terminated with the ‘&’ control operator, with a two-way pipe established between the executing shell and the coprocess.
>
> The format for a coprocess is:

```
coproc [NAME] command [redirections]
```

Comment: I wouldn't touch `coproc`. When the co-process exits, the variables through which you accessed it (like its stdout file descriptor) are unset, and that sometimes happens before you had a chance to even start consuming the output, or capture the PID. (Try consuming the output of `ls`, and then do it again with sleep before you consume. Ops...) So maybe your script works most of the time, but when timings are less lucky, it randomly fails. Named pipes, on the other hand, will not be suddenly gone. It's more fiddling, but at least it's deterministic.

Comment: @ddekany, usually, coprocesses are workers, thus they wait for the input. In case of short-lived "output" program don't use async commands, use something like `$(ls)` instead.

Comment: I agree, coprocess is really a great and convenient feature, but with the one disappointing limitation. There is a BUGS section in `man bash` at the very end, and it is stated that `There may be only one active coprocess at a time.`

Answer (score 9):

While @DavidAnderson's [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1405693/37154) covers all the bases and offers some nice safeguards, the most important thing it reveals is that getting your hands on an anonymous pipe is as easy as `<(:)`, as long as you stay on Linux.

So the shortest and simplest answer to your question is:

```
exec 5<> <(:)
```

On macOS it won't work, then you'll need to create a temporary directory to house the named fifo in until you've redirected to it. I don't know about other BSDs.

Comment: You do realize your answer only works because of a bug in linux. This bug does not exist in macOS, thus requiring the more complex solution. The final version I posted will work in linux even if the bug in linux is fixed.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Sounds like you have deeper knowledge of this than I do. Why is the Linux behavior a bug?

Comment: If `exec` is passed and anonymous fifo that is opened only for reading, then `exec` should not allow this anonymous fifo to be opened for read and writing using a custom file descriptor. You should expect to get a `-bash: /dev/fd/5: Permission denied` message, which is what macOS issues. I believe the bug is  that Ubuntu does not produce the same message. I would be willing to change my  mind if someone could produce documentation saying `exec 5<> <(:)` is explicated permitted.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Wow, that's fascinating. I assumed bash was doing something internally, but it turns out it's Linux that allows simply doing `open(..., O_RDWR)` on one unidirectional pipe end provided by the substitution and that turns it into a bidirectional pipe in one FD. You're probably right that one shouldn't rely on this. :-D Output from using [execline's piperw](https://www.skarnet.org/software/execline/piperw.html) to create the pipe, then repurposing it with bash `<>`: https://libranet.de/display/0b6b25a8-195c-84af-6ac7-ee6696661765

Comment: Not that it matters, but if you want to see under Ubuntu what is passed to `exec 5<>` , then enter `fun() { ls -l $1; ls -lH $1; }; fun <(:)`.

Comment: I know that `<(:)` gives you a `/dev/fd/<FD>` string, but thought that maybe `<>` modifies the behavior of the thing that file path is pointing at. Your example cannot answer that question, only reading the bash grammar and internal functions could achieve that, so I did. As it turns out, as I said, bash does nothing special at all, it just does something that should fail, and doesn't mind that it happens to work.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Could you link to a reference stating why this is a bug?

Comment: @alecov: I currently have no link to a reference stating why this is a bug. My [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/184307/bash-create-anonymous-fifo/1405693#1405693) has other links you may wish to reference.

Comment: I'd say MacOS has the bug. Say we have a "/dev/fd/42" that is just the read end of a pipe.   Why **not** allow it to be opened `open("/dev/fd/42", O_RDWR)`?   It only has to fail if someone actually attempts to perform a write.

Comment: A pipe being open in the read direction is not exactly the esame as a `r--r-----` permission. Secondly, even if it was a permission-like situation, it still has to be checked at I/O time. Just like for a file. If we have a `rwxrwxr-x` file that successfully opens for writing to its owner, and **then** the permission is changed to `r-xr-xr-x`, subsequent writes on that descriptor must fail, even though it opened.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, this is exactly what I was looking for (ideally there would be a builtin for selecting an unused fd). As I understand it @DavidAnderson's reservations stem from opening it bidirectionally, `exec 5< <(:)` is plenty enough for my usage.

Comment: @Kaz, thanks! It makes the situation clearer. I think I'll be using anonymous instead of named pipes as it is much cleaner.

Comment: @MayeulC, `> ideally there would be a builtin for selecting an unused fd` Actually, there is a way to allocate FD automatically: `exec {FD}<> <(:)`, `echo hello >&$FD`

Comment: @Alek Interesting, thank you for pointing this out. https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html seems to document this: "Each redirection that may be preceded by a file descriptor number may instead be preceded by a word of the form {varname}. In this case, for each redirection operator [...], the shell will allocate a file descriptor greater than 10 and assign it to {varname}"

Answer (score 3):

As of October 2012 this functionality still doesn't seem to exist in Bash, but coproc can be used if all you need unnamed/anonymous pipes for is to talk to a child process. Problem with coproc at this point is that apparently only one is supported at a time. I can't figure out why coproc got this limitation. They should have been an enhancement of the existing task backgrounding code (the & op), but that's a question for the authors of bash.

Comment: Not only one coprocess is supported. You can name them, as long as you don't provide a simple command. Give it a command list instead: `coproc THING { dothing; }` Now your FDs are in `${THING[*]}` and you can run `coproc OTHERTHING { dothing; }` and send and receive things to and from both.

Comment: @clacke in `man bash`, under the BUGS title, they say this: _There may be only one active coprocess at a time_. And you get a warning if you start a second coproc. It appears to work, but I don't know what explodes in the background.

Comment: Ok, so it currently only works by luck, not because it was intentional. Fair warning, thanks. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The following function was tested using `GNU bash, version 4.4.19(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`. The operating system was Ubuntu 18. This function take a single parameter which is the desired file descriptor for the anonymous FIFO.

```
MakeFIFO() {
    local "MakeFIFO_upper=$(ulimit -n)" 
    if [[ $# -ne 1 || ${#1} -gt ${#MakeFIFO_upper} || -n ${1%%[0-9]*} || 10#$1 -le 2
        || 10#$1 -ge MakeFIFO_upper ]] || eval ! exec "$1<> " <(:) 2>"/dev/null"; then
        echo "$FUNCNAME: $1: Could not create FIFO" >&2
        return "1"
    fi
}
```

The following function was tested using `GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin17)`. The operating system was macOS High Sierra. This function starts out by created a named FIFO in an temporary directory *known only to the process that created it*. Next, the file descriptor is redirected to the FIFO. Finally, the FIFO is unlinked from from the filename by deleting the temporary directory. This makes the FIFO anonymous.

```
MakeFIFO() {
    MakeFIFO.SetStatus() {
        return "${1:-$?}"
    }
    MakeFIFO.CleanUp() {
        local "MakeFIFO_status=$?"
        rm -rf "${MakeFIFO_directory:-}"    
        unset "MakeFIFO_directory"
        MakeFIFO.SetStatus "$MakeFIFO_status" && true
        eval eval "${MakeFIFO_handler:-:}'; true'" 
    }
    local "MakeFIFO_success=false" "MakeFIFO_upper=$(ulimit -n)" "MakeFIFO_file=" 
    MakeFIFO_handler="$(trap -p EXIT)"
    MakeFIFO_handler="${MakeFIFO_handler#trap -- }"
    MakeFIFO_handler="${MakeFIFO_handler% *}"
    trap -- 'MakeFIFO.CleanUp' EXIT
    until "$MakeFIFO_success"; do
        [[ $# -eq 1 && ${#1} -le ${#MakeFIFO_upper} && -z ${1%%[0-9]*}
        && 10#$1 -gt 2 && 10#$1 -lt MakeFIFO_upper ]] || break
        MakeFIFO_directory=$(mktemp -d) 2>"/dev/null" || break
        MakeFIFO_file="$MakeFIFO_directory/pipe"
        mkfifo -m 600 $MakeFIFO_file 2>"/dev/null" || break
        ! eval ! exec "$1<> $MakeFIFO_file" 2>"/dev/null" || break
        MakeFIFO_success="true"
    done
    rm -rf "${MakeFIFO_directory:-}"
    unset  "MakeFIFO_directory"
    eval trap -- "$MakeFIFO_handler" EXIT
    unset  "MakeFIFO_handler"
    "$MakeFIFO_success" || { echo "$FUNCNAME: $1: Could not create FIFO" >&2; return "1"; }
}
```

The above functions can be combined to a single function that will work on both operating systems. Below is an example of such a function. Here, an attempt is made to create a truly anonymous FIFO. If unsuccessfully, then a named FIFO is created and converted to an anonymous FIFO.

```
MakeFIFO() {
    MakeFIFO.SetStatus() {
        return "${1:-$?}"
    }
    MakeFIFO.CleanUp() {
        local "MakeFIFO_status=$?"
        rm -rf "${MakeFIFO_directory:-}"    
        unset "MakeFIFO_directory"
        MakeFIFO.SetStatus "$MakeFIFO_status" && true
        eval eval "${MakeFIFO_handler:-:}'; true'" 
    }
    local "MakeFIFO_success=false" "MakeFIFO_upper=$(ulimit -n)" "MakeFIFO_file=" 
    MakeFIFO_handler="$(trap -p EXIT)"
    MakeFIFO_handler="${MakeFIFO_handler#trap -- }"
    MakeFIFO_handler="${MakeFIFO_handler% *}"
    trap -- 'MakeFIFO.CleanUp' EXIT
    until "$MakeFIFO_success"; do
        [[ $# -eq 1 && ${#1} -le ${#MakeFIFO_upper} && -z ${1%%[0-9]*}
        && 10#$1 -gt 2 && 10#$1 -lt MakeFIFO_upper ]] || break
        if eval ! exec "$1<> " <(:) 2>"/dev/null"; then
            MakeFIFO_directory=$(mktemp -d) 2>"/dev/null" || break
            MakeFIFO_file="$MakeFIFO_directory/pipe"
            mkfifo -m 600 $MakeFIFO_file 2>"/dev/null" || break
            ! eval ! exec "$1<> $MakeFIFO_file" 2>"/dev/null" || break
        fi
        MakeFIFO_success="true"
    done
    rm -rf "${MakeFIFO_directory:-}"
    unset  "MakeFIFO_directory"
    eval trap -- "$MakeFIFO_handler" EXIT
    unset  "MakeFIFO_handler"
    "$MakeFIFO_success" || { echo "$FUNCNAME: $1: Could not create FIFO" >&2; return "1"; }
}
```

Here is an example of creating an anonymous FIFO, then writing some text to the same FIFO.

```
fd="6"
MakeFIFO "$fd"
echo "Now is the" >&"$fd"
echo "time for all" >&"$fd"
echo "good men" >&"$fd"
```

Below is an example of reading the entire contents of the anonymous FIFO.

```
echo "EOF" >&"$fd"
while read -u "$fd" message; do
    [[ $message != *EOF ]] || break
    echo "$message"
done
```

This produces the following output.

```
Now is the
time for all
good men
```

The command below closes the anonymous FIFO.

```
eval exec "$fd>&-"
```

**References:**
[Creating an anonymous pipe for later use](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-bash/2014-10/msg00046.html)
[Files in Publicly Writable Directories Are Dangerous](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/SecureCodingGuide/Articles/RaceConditions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002585-SW15)
[Shell Script Security](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/OpenSource/Conceptual/ShellScripting/ShellScriptSecurity/ShellScriptSecurity.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004268-CH8)

Answer (score 0):

Using the great and bright answer from htamas, I modified it a little to use it in an one liner, here it is:

```
# create a temporary named pipe
PIPE=(`(exec 0</dev/null 1</dev/null; (( read -d \  e < /proc/self/stat ; echo $e >&2 ; exec tail -f /dev/null 2> /dev/null ) | ( read -d \  e < /proc/self/stat ; echo $e  >&2 ; exec tail -f /dev/null 2> /dev/null )) &) 2>&1 | for ((i=0; i<2; i++)); do read e; printf "$e "; done`)
# attach it to file descriptors 3 and 4
exec 3>/proc/${PIPE[0]}/fd/1 4</proc/${PIPE[1]}/fd/0
...
# kill the temporary pids
kill ${PIPE[@]}
...
# anything we write to fd 3 can be read back from fd 4
echo 'Hello world!' >&3
head -n1 <&4
...
# close the file descriptor when we are finished (optional)
exec 3>&- 4<&-
```

Comment: I can't help noticing that your *one-liner* has more than one line.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my contribution

```
# open an anonymous pipe, put the read handle in variable named $1 
# and the write handle in variable named $2
# WARNING: Be careful about closing write handles for read commands/subshells, 
# or the read-handle may never get eof
# e.g. do this:
# good:   mkpipe r w ; ( fd-close $w  ; cat <&${r} ; ) & echo hello >${w}
# better: mkpipe r w ; ( fd-close $w  ; cat <&${r} ; ) & fd-close $r ; echo hello >${w}
mk2pipe() {
  mkfifo $(mktemp -u) && local header_pipe="$_" || return $?
  # the <> keeps it open both ways long enough for us to open a read and a write handle without blocking
  eval exec "{_}<>'$header_pipe' {$1}<'$header_pipe' {$2}>'$header_pipe' {_}<&-"
  set $?
  rm -f "$header_pipe"
  return $?
}

with-fd-close() {
  eval '"${@:2}"' "$1<&-"
}

fd-close() {
  while test $# != 0
  do # if it is not a pure number, treat it as a var name
     if test -n "$1" -a -z "${1//[0-9]/}"
     then eval exec "$1<&-"
     else eval exec "${!1}<&-"
          printf -v "$1" "CLOSED-FD-${!1}"
     fi
     shift
  done
}

test-mk2pipe() {
  local BASH_XTRACEFD=2
  local -
  set -x

  local w r
  mk2pipe r w || return $?
  with-fd-close $w exec sed -e 's/^/===/g' <&${r} &
  sleep 1
  fd-close $r
  ls >&${w}
  fd-close $w # should cause sub-process to quit
  wait $!

  mk2pipe r w || return $?
  echo hello >&${w}
  fd-close $w
  sleep 1
  with-fd-close $w exec cat <&${r}
  fd-close $r
  wait $!
}
```

Answer (score -1):

htamas answer with tail commands works well, but have a race condition. Here an explanation and a binary that resolve it - https://github.com/Z-Wave-Me/mkpipe .

Comment: Answers should quote and cite the relevant information from an external resource.  Answers that only contain a link to an external resource are not allowed.

Comment: @Ramhound OMG... I've already done this - i've written that "have a race condition". If somebody want a details, then he can read it on the linked page. Ramhound, do this a reason for downvote?

Comment: Voting is anonymous

Comment: @Oleg I did not get either. `# Is this enough to finish with children?` what children should be finished? what are we waiting for there?